# Does action on $X$ define an action on cohomology $H^i(X,F)$?

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $F$ a sheaf on $X$, given an automorphism $f\colon X\to X$, do we have an induced morphism $H^i(X,F)\to H^i(X,F)$ for any sheaf on $X$?(I can understand for $(X,f^*F)\to (Y,F)$, there's a map $H^i(Y,F)\to H^i(X,f^*F)$, given by $H^i(Y,F)\to H^i(Y,f_*f^*F)\to H^i(X,f^*F)$, where the last step is given by choosing an resolution of $f^*F\to I^\cdot$ and define by induced map on hypercohomology for $f_*f^*F\to f^*I^\cdot$, LHS viewed as complex concentrated at degree $0$)

Comment: $F$ needs to have the extra structure of being equivariant with respect to this action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merely by transport of structure, there is a natural map (covariant in $f$) $H^i(X,F)\to H^i(X,f_*F)$; equivalently, replacing $f$ by its inverse, there is a natural map $H^i(X,f^*F)\to H^i(X,F)$ contravariant in $f$ (note that $f_*$ and $f^*$ are inverse functors when $f$ is a homeomorphism).  However, there is no reason there should be a natural map $H^i(X,F)\to H^i(X,F)$ associated to $f$, because $f$ is only an automorphism of $X$, not of the pair $(X,F)$.  I don't know how to prove rigorously that no such (sufficiently nice) natural map exists, but I see no reason at all to expect there to be one.  If you are unconvinced, then I ask you: what do you think the map should be in the case $i=0$?

Comment: I was thinking about Lefschetz trace formula, it works for constant sheaves, and there's a version for general sheaves and Frobenius morphism, I was wondering in that case how maps on cohomology were induced. After your explanation, I realized a map $Fr^*F\to F$ was also defined to make things work in that context,

Comment: Wait... I was still confused.. In case of constant sheaves, does action on $X$ induce action on compactly supported cohomology? That is, suppose $i\colon X\to \overline{X}$ is an open immersion into a compact space, We define $H_c^i(X,\mathbb{Z}/n)$ to be $H^i(\overline{X},i_!\mathbb{Z}/n)$, this is not a constant sheaf, is there a natural action?

Comment: If the sheaf is defined in a canonical way on $X$ (using only the fact that $X$ has certain structure), any automorphism of $f$ (which preserves that structure) is also an automorphism of the pair $(X,F)$, so any object that can canonically be defined from the pair $(X,F)$ is functorial with respect to such automorphisms.